# How do I run an asynchronous $.getJSON function within a loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code that is searching for synonyms of a list of vocabulary `newvocabpasted` from an API.

Each list returned is added to an array `obj`. (I end up with an array of arrays - this is what I want).

The problem is that the `data` from the request gets returned in different orders when I run the code at different times. This leads to an issue that will tell me that a member of the vocab list searched for has incorrect synonyms.

I assumed this was because of the asynchronous nature of the getJSON call - so tried the async/await approach. But - I'm still having problems.

Why doesn't the code 'wait' in the function? And - if it does - and the rest of the function is running around it... how do I solve my problem?

```
    p = 0;
        for (m of  newvocabpasted) {
            console.log("Loop:"+p);
            //search online for list of synoynyms of newvocabpasted[p]
            q1 = "https://words.bighugelabs.com/api/1/754ccc845dff7cb4459e3b40365609fb/",
            q2 = "/",
            q3 = "json";
            query = q1+m+q2+q3;
            console.log("Looking for:"+m);
            $.getJSON(query,
                async function(data) {
                    //put results in elements of an array called obj
                    console.log(p);
                    obj[p] = await data;
                    console.log(p);
                    console.log(obj[p]);
                    await p++;
                });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't the code 'wait' in the function?

You have to await a **promise**, not an arbitrary value. Neither `data` not `p` are promises.

`$.getJSON` returns a promise. That is what you need to `await`.

Comment: Yes - thank you. I can see that now. I mistakenly saw data as the promise.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an example using promises so that you can understand what's happening.

```js
// We use "async" in a function every time we are going to deal with promises.
$(async function () {

  const url = 'https://words.bighugelabs.com/api/1/754ccc845dff7cb4459e3b40365609fb/';
  const words = ['go','stay','run'];
  
  for (let w of words) {  
      // Since $.get returns a promise, we use await to catch the result from it once the request is fullfilled.
      const res = await $.get(url + w);
      
      // Split all the results in order to create an array.
      const arrResults = res.split('\n');
      
      // Promises get fullfilled in the same order as requested.
      console.log(w, arrResults.length);
  }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you - it did help. I can now see that the  $.getJSON was needing to awaited and the function that my code was in is the async function.